# Row counter Openerp - Item Custom Module

Tags: python, module, counter, odoo

I need to count and show the number of items, of for example a `purchase.order.line` and show them on an `integer` type field.

For example in a `purchase.order` i add 13 items, or products; this field, will store and then show outside the `purchase.order.line` the quantity of items of this purchase.

I've looked in stackexchange, and in the openerp books, but no luck in finding a an example of such a function.

Any module or existing functon should i look for?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure what you are asking.  Do you mean that if you have a purchase order with 13 lines, you want a field on the purchase order to show the sum of the quantity fields on the 13 order lines?

If so, you need to extend the purchase.order model and add a functional field that will iterate through the order lines and total the quantity.

Your column would be:

```
'total_quantity': fields.function(_get_total_quantity, type='float', method = True, string = 'Total Quantity', readonly = True),
```

Your method would be:

```
def _get_total_quantity(self, cr, uid, ids, field, args, context = None):
    res = {}
    for po in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context = context):
        res[po.id] = sum([x.quantity for x in po.order_line])

    return res
```

Please check that the name of the one2many on purchase.order for the purchase order lines is "order_line".  I am doing this from memory and I can't remember the column name.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, but i need it exactly for a custum module, similar to purchase.order, minimized of course, so i think i'm gonna change "order_line" to suit my "custom_line" is that correct?

Comment: And yes, 'order_line' is the field in purchase.py

Comment: Nevermind, i just made a substitution, assigned a 'cc' variable in place of the 'po', and substituted the order_line for Cert_ids, cert_ids being my equivalent of order_line, thank you very very much!